# When does the UIColletionView calls his datasource and delegate methods

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I created a *UICollectionView* with a custom cell. In the *viewDidLoad()* method I was registering my cellclass.

```
   collectionView?.register(CustomCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)
  collectionView?.reloadData()
```

While debugging my code to check the behavior I saw that in the line where I was registering my collectionView and called collectionView.reloadData()  with the custom Cellclass none of the datasource and delegate methods got executed like cellForItem at etc.. ? Why is that so ?

Comment: what do you mean by nothing happened? did you set your data source and delegate?

Comment: Yes I set my datasource and delegate and the collectionView works fine because I'm calling self.collectionView.reloadData inside of another function . I just wondered why none of the methods like cellForItem at etc.  were not executed inside of viewDidLoad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`viewDidLoad()` is called when your view has finished loading but *before* the view is laid out i.e. before its frame is properly set.

Judging from my observations a collection view calls its data source methods (like `cellForItem(at:)`) lazily during the layout process. After all, it doesn't need to call the data source methods at all if its size is `.zero` or if its position is currently off-screen!

#### So to put it short:

There is no reason why your collection view's data source methods *should* be called in `viewDidLoad()`.

---

As far as I know calling `reloadData()` only discards all visible cells and decoration views so that they *must* be reloaded during the next layout pass. When the collection view is currently visible a new layout pass is triggered immediately but in `viewDidLoad()` the collection view isn't even on screen yet. (`viewDidAppear()` has not been called yet.)

Answer (score 0):

Deffinately strange staff you are doing, after registering cell, you are reloading collectionView data.. Why? You should reload data when something changes in your array of data. But anyhow, try to call reloadData on the main thread.

```
DispathQueue.main.async {
   self.collecitonView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: I know that this is weird I just did that to understand the behavior of the collectionView. I thought when registering the cell inside of viewDidLoad the datasource and delegate methods will be called initial. When I saw nothing happened I tried reloadData. So at which point the datasource and delegate methods will be called. I thought when registering the cellClass =

Comment: Yes, delegate methods should be called. Try to show us your implementation, so we can help you.. But for now, have no idea what to suggest you. May be you forgot something to implement, cause this collectionView is a bit tricky..